# Circle features missing in PostGIS after import from ArcGIS using ogr2ogr

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, mapserver, ogr, circle

I have a ArcGIS feature class of geometry type polygon. It was created as a convex hull with a 200 meter buffer on a point dataset, aggregating rows on a particular field. The number of points used to generate each polygon is variable, starting at 1. I use ogr2ogr to upload from a personal geodatabase (.MDB) to a remote PostGIS database, and MapServer 5.4 to display. All features are uploaded successfully, but those polygon features that were generated from a single point do not plot using MapServer. Based on how the polygons are generated, all those based on a single point ought to be circles with radii of 200 meters.

In the PostGIS table the geometry field is empty for all those features, and following a tip I found here I tried "select st_npoints(wkb_geometry) from merged_dist_areas;" and it appears all the "missing" polygon features have no points at all, which may explain why they do not plot.

What can I do to plot these circles?

Comment: As the answer says "too many unknown here to say anything about where the failure has happened" so to progress this further we would need you to provide precise details of your procedure leading up to where what you observed deviated from what you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is finding out where in this chain something has gone wrong. As I understand it you did the geoprocessing in ArcGIS? Did you confirm that the 200 meter circles was properly created?

There is too many unknown here to say anything about where the failure has happened.

But if I were you I would just import the original table and do the processing in PostGIS. Then it will also be easier to find what is failing.

In PostGIS it would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Convexhull(ST_Collect(the_geom))) as the_geom
from point_table group by group_field;
```

Comment: The circles appear to be correctly generated and plotted in ArcGIS.

I just tried a new upload by exporting from ArcGIS to a shapefile and uploading using the shapefile loader in PgAdmin, and it appears to work. At least there are points in all the resulting polygon geometries now.
Perhaps there is something with the ogr2ogr personal geodatabase driver that's missing. I will check for a new version and report back. Thanks for the processing tip, I will try that next.

Comment: ok, what is the reault of st_astext(the_geom) on the not working geometries. maybe arcgis creates a circle from curves when using buffer on a foint. maybe ogr2ogr just passes this curve to postgis. postgis understand curves but I don't think Mapserver does. shapefile don't handle curves so arcgis converts when exporting to shape.

Comment: Using ogr2ogr to import from the personal geodatabase the st_astext function returns empty geometries for the non-working features, and all working features are inserted as POLYGON. There are no errors reported by ogr2ogr. Using the shapefile loader all features work, are inserted as MULTIPOLYGON, and the circles all have 101 points.
I downloaded the latest version of FWTools and tried the ogr2ogr supplied there and now get an informative error:
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR: geometry requires more points.

Comment: Following your hint about curves above, this topic appeared http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/fwtools/2008-November/001430.html . One sentence may summarize the problem I am experiencing: "No, OGR does not support curves from the personal geodatabase". From what I can determine, ArcGIS does in fact store circles as curves, except in shapefiles.

Comment: ok, then you have found the problem :-) little strange behavior of arcgis to cerate a curve just in the special case when buffering a point and apparently not as part of other buffering. handloing curves will just give you trouble like you just have expåerienced. choose the best way to get rid if them. the export path through shape file or do the processing in PostGIS.